# SERVEROUTPUT shows results one after another execution

Tags: oracle, plsql

When I execute the following trigger code it is compiled. Then after inserting data, serveroutput says '1 row inserted' trigger result ('User Example has insrted a data') didn't displayed.

Then after execution of another PL/SQL the previous trigger result will appears on display. What should i do to solve this issue?

Here is the trigger and the insertion command and also the results,

```
/
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER BTR_SUPERHEROS
BEFORE INSERT ON SUPERHEROS
FOR EACH ROW
ENABLE

DECLARE
    V_USER VARCHAR2(30);
BEGIN
    SELECT USER INTO V_USER FROM DUAL;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE();
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('USER:' ||V_USER||' HAS INSERTED A DATA');
END;
/
```

**RESULT -** Trigger BTR_SUPERHEROS compiled

INSERT INTO SUPERHEROS VALUES('SUPERMAN');

**RESULT -** 1 row inserted. (Didn't Shows the DBMS_OUTPUT)

Comment: Nowhere related to java

Comment: WHY DO YOU FEEL THE NEED TO SHOUT AT US?

Comment: i don't know how to solve this please help me

Comment: @AravindaRathnayake Did the given answer resolved your problem? Then please accept it as an answer or post follow up questions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to [`set serveroutput on`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQPUG/ch_twelve040.htm#SQPUG099) in the client application (SQL*Plus, SQL Developer etc) in the session where you run a statement, otherwise it won't know that you want it fetch and display the output buffer when the statement completes. The `set server output on` prior to creating the trigger is just a client setting and doesn't set it permanently for the trigger.

Please confirm whether your test case was run from a single session, like this:

```
SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.1.0 Production on Tue Aug 15 08:17:48 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Last Successful login time: Tue Aug 15 2017 08:14:08 +01:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing options

SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
SQL>
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER BTR_SUPERHEROS
  2  BEFORE INSERT ON SUPERHEROS
  3  FOR EACH ROW
  4  ENABLE
  5
  6  DECLARE
  7      V_USER VARCHAR2(30);
  8  BEGIN
  9      SELECT USER INTO V_USER FROM DUAL;
 10      DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE();
 11      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('USER:' ||V_USER||' HAS INSERTED A DATA');
 12  END;
 13  /

Trigger created.

SQL> INSERT INTO SUPERHEROS VALUES('SUPERMAN');
USER:WILLIAM HAS INSERTED A DATA

1 row created.
```

Note also that it is not recommended to call `dbms_output.enable`. From [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_output.htm#ARPLS67303):

> You should generally avoid having application code invoke either the DISABLE Procedure or ENABLE Procedure because this could subvert the attempt of an external tool like SQL*Plus to control whether or not to display output.

You can also assign values using the assignment `:=` operator instead of a `select into` statement. The trigger could therefore be written as:

```
create or replace trigger btr_superheros
before insert on superheros
for each row
enable
declare
    v_user user_users.username%type := sys_context('userenv', 'current_schema');
begin
    dbms_output.put_line('User: ' ||v_user||' inserted value '''||:new.name||'''');
end;
/
```